# Dry out this code snippet (without dirtying up the namespace too much)

Tags: c, dry, namespace-organisation

I had

```
for (i = 1; i < max_i; i++) {
  e[i] == 1 ? printf("%ld", p[i]) : printf("%ld^%ld", p[i], e[i]);
}
```

in a loop, but then needed to write multiplication signs between the elements (but not the first). I didn't want

```
e[1] == 1 ? printf("%ld", p[1]) : printf("%ld^%ld", p[1], e[1]);
for (i = 2; i < max_i; i++) {
  e[i] == 1 ? printf(" * %ld", p[i]) : printf(" * %ld^%ld", p[i], e[i]);
}
```

so I write a quick, one-time function

```
void
show_pe(int p, int e)
{
    if (e == 1)
        printf("%ld", p);
    else
        printf("%ld^%ld", p, e);
}
```

which, despite dirtying up the namespace, removed the duplication nicely. But now I see that the following functions have similar code not covered by my quick function. I'd need

```
void
show_e_p(int p, int e)
{
    if (e == 1)
        printf("%ld", p);
    else
        printf("%ld*%ld", e, p);
}
```

and

```
void
show_pe_outside(int p, int e)
{
    if (e == 1)
        printf("a(%ld)", p);
    else
        printf("a(%ld)^%ld", p, e);
}
```

and a host of others. But since these would only be used twice each, two lines apart, this seems wasteful (and separates code from its natural place, rarely a good thing). Surely there's a better way! Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

```
do {
  code block to be executed
} while (condition);
```

ie - consider changing your loops so that the duplicated code is not duplicated anymore..

Comment: Doesn't fit my use case, because I need different code to run in addition to the snippet when i > 1.

Comment: fair enough. Your first example (above) does not show that. though the later functions do... you might want to edit your first example to reflect that ;)

Comment: wait no I'm wrong... your duplication is this block: `e[1] == 1 ? printf("%ld", p[1]) : printf("%ld^%ld", p[1], e[1]);`
it's the same both times...

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't just have the loop start at 1  and then have an if-block around the bits that aren't run when i === 1

Comment: I need `printf(" * ")` on runs 2 through n. Easy enough to add, harder to do without duplication.

Comment: Ugly, but maybe that's the best I can do.

Comment: ie - your example above doesn't actually show any reason for why you'd need to start the loop at 2 - can you update your example so it actually makes sense? :)

Comment: You're right, of course. I've accepted; sorry if I wasn't quite clear at first.

Comment: P.S. Here's the code: https://github.com/CRGreathouse/PARI-extensions/blob/master/numth.gp.c#L926